# Is there a parts list for Light Stax pieces anywhere?

Tags: clone-brands, part-database

Light Stax is a clone product that focuses on electrically lit bricks.

It basically works like the 1990s era Lego 9V connector plates - contacts embedded into studs and negative studs, so any Light Stax pieces you put on top of each other do not only hold together physically, but also conducts electricity.

On the [Light Stax website](https://www.light-stax.de/), some of the boxes are shown from various sides, which reveals a parts listing of a couple of sets, but there does not seem to be a complete listing of available parts anywhere. For instance, the [box photo of the connectors and cables set](https://www.light-stax.de/shop/article/stax-expansion-cables-connectors-lego-kompatibel.html) reveals there are also unlit conductor plates.

**Is there a complete list of the different parts (especially the ones that are not just bricks, but that have any of the power functions) Light Stax produces anywhere?**

Comment: The building instructions on the website do have a part list of the respective set. However, I am not aware of a complete list.